# ECC - complex multiplication and key agreement

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation

I'd like to ask three questions - 2 of them regard CM method. The last is regarding the ECC domain parameters generation on the fly, see https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/647.pdf

1. What role has discriminant $D$? When generating new curve, what I should choose as $D$? I saw $D=1$, but other source says is should be bigger number, so I dont know...
2. The same as 1), but what is class-number explanation for dummies?
3. In the source I provided, they discuss on the fly generation of parameters. I understand that every end-point generate new elliptic curve group with CM method for just one DH key agreement, but **I dont understand how this end-point can communicate with other party**. If both parties want to communicate, **they need to have same ell. curve group**, but how they can have same group if every of them randomly generates their own group...?

Thanks for any comment.
Daniel